# LinkedIn API People Search

Tags: http, post, get, linkedin-api

I haven't seen any questions around this topic after 2019 so I've decided to ask some. The topic is LinkedIn v1 and v2 APIs.

- Are there any "GET" requests that let me get a list of people from a people
  search?
- Are there any other features that would let me send messages through
  LinkedIn's API?

I'm working in python3 and:

```
linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=some_address, scope=scope)

linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
                      include_client_id=True,
                      authorization_response=redirect_response)

linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?keywords=Astronaut')
```

Apparently this resource is no longer supported. Any suggestions on how to do this with v2 or anything else?